# Splitting a string of hex values with delimiter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, delimiter

I have a string of hex values:-

```
ffffe7ba2cffffe7c52cffffe7c22cffffe7c12cffffe7c82cffffe7c62cffffe7b52cffffe7a02c
```

I want to split this string using the delimiter value `"2c"`.

I tried with `.split(0x2c)`, `.split("2c")`, `.split(b'\x2c')`, but none seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result.?

Comment: And what are you getting at the moment? Please post the complete code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
myHex = 0xffffe7ba2cffffe7c52cffffe7c22cffffe7c12cffffe7c82cffffe7c62cffffe7b52cffffe7a02c
myStringForHex = str(hex(myHex))[2:]
myStringForHex.split('2c')
```

The corresponding output is :

```
['ffffe7ba',
 'ffffe7c5',
 'ffffe7c2',
 'ffffe7c1',
 'ffffe7c8',
 'ffffe7c6',
 'ffffe7b5',
 'ffffe7a0',
 '']
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! How can I write these values vertically to a text file without the single quotes and commas?

Comment: ```fh = open("container.txt",'w')
for val in vals:
    fh.write(val+"\n")```

Answer (score 1):

Which Python version are you using?

In Python 3.7 the follwing code seems to work:

```
tmp = "ffffe7ba2cffffe7c52cffffe7c22cffffe7c12cffffe7c82cffffe7c62cffffe7b52cffffe7a02c"
tmp.split("2c")

Out[37]: 
['ffffe7ba',
 'ffffe7c5',
 'ffffe7c2',
 'ffffe7c1',
 'ffffe7c8',
 'ffffe7c6',
 'ffffe7b5',
 'ffffe7a0',
 '']
```

Or what would your desired output be?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me.

```
In [1]: s = "ffffe7ba2cffffe7c52cffffe7c22cffffe7c12cffffe7c82cffffe7c62cffffe7b52cffffe7a02c"
In [2]: s.split("2c")
Out[2]: 
['ffffe7ba',
 'ffffe7c5',
 'ffffe7c2',
 'ffffe7c1',
 'ffffe7c8',
 'ffffe7c6',
 'ffffe7b5',
 'ffffe7a0',
 '']
```